# Failing to connect Workspace with AKS monitoring on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-log-analytics

AKS ab-aks1 was connected to Workspace la1 in Subscription sub1 and sub2 respectively and I moved la1 to a new Subscription sub3, now that before the move I deleted the solution I need to connect ab-aks1 in sub1 to la1 in sub3 but I'm getting an error:
[image]

```
BadRequestError: Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: We are unable to serve this request due to an internal error on fetching log analytics workspace key with error:
```

Nothing that could be found on Google/MS related to this, maybe someone faced it knows how to resolve this.

Comment: do you still have the issue? how about do it from UI?

Comment: It's resolved, please check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue when we tried to deploy it via release pipeline. Service principal AzureContainerService needs Log analytics contributor permission on the resource group in which Log Analytics workspace is deployed.